# How to change hint in export table?

Tags: c, function, dll, dllimport, dllexport

I'm trying to export functions from my DLL, with a custom hint. Currently I am exporting functions with custom symbols and custom ordinal, but I've been unable to change the hint of the exported functions.

This is my .def file

```
LIBRARY "freeMart"
EXPORTS
  beginValidation@4 @7 NONAME
  endValidation@4 @8
```

My program is a C DLL. I've searched across the entire internet, asked experienced individuals and even tried asking AI, but I couldn't find any help regarding how to do this. I've also read through the entire documentation on .def files and DLL function exporting on the Microsoft website [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/build/reference/exports?view=msvc-170)

I've tried doing stuff like this with no success.

```
LIBRARY "freeMart"
EXPORTS
  beginValidation@4 @7 @1 NONAME
  endValidation@4 @8 @2
```

and

`void __stdcall beginValidation(unsigned int testCase) = 0;`

Comment: What's the whole purpose of this (or what's a function hint)? The *URL* you posted states pretty much everything that's (officially) supported.